# Scala/Lift vs Java/Spring. Why fighting?

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-mvc, lift

I'm new to Spring, Lift, and Scala and I don't understand why there is so much fighting over these technologies. I found many people in different forums comparing and fighting over both the two programming languages and the two frameworks. Besides the differences of Java/Lift languages, why is there so much talking about Spring vs Lift?

- Spring is an ***application*** framework.
- Lift is a ***web*** framework.

Aren't the two frameworks conceptually separated?

Of course Lift overlaps and competes with Spring's MVC module for front-end development, but doesn't Spring do much more?

Also, if anyone prefers building a web application using Lift, wouldn't it be just possible to combine/integrate Lift with an existing Spring's infrastructure and having an environment with Java, Scala, Spring, and Lift all together?

Comment: People just love flame wars. My dad is stronger than your dad.

Comment: @biziclop, I don't agree with you. Nobody can beat my dad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this question is appropriate for stack overflow. This is psychological phenomenon, through which an individual becomes defensive about the choices he makes and hostile to the suggestions that they might be wrong.

I've heard this explained in at least two different ways. One, these choices become part of the sense of self of the individual, so that he interprets threats to them as threats to himself. The other, the sense of reasoning of humans did not evolve to find the "truth", but, rather, to convince others -- their impulse, when discussing, is not to ascertain facts, but to get the others to his own point of view.

As for why Lift and Spring intersect, you said

> Of course Lift overlaps and competes with Spring's MVC module for
>   front-end development, but doesn't Spring do much more?

Well, *Spring* does much more, but do *people* do much more with Spring? By and large, no. People for whom Spring actually does mean much more probably don't care at all about such discussions.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Daniel. Unfortunately people get emotionally attached to their ideas, their point of view, and the technologies they chose to use.. "I am my position" , "The enemy is out there".. Knowing how to deal with divergent opinions is fundamental in order to establish a learning reinforcing feedback among an organization, a team, or a group of friends. Getting rid of mental models and being able to separate ideas from people is the only way to get to the "truth" and to benefit from it. If you're interested: "The Fifth Discipline" - Peter M. Senge